# Consulta MySQL para seleccionar el 35% de registros de una tabla?

Tags: mysql, porcentaje

¿Como hago un query en MYSQL para seleccionar el primer 35% de registros de una tabla?
Intenté esto:

```
    Select * from tabla limit 0,35%    (???)
    Select * from tabla limit 0,(count(*)/100)*35
```

Estos códigos anteriores no funcionan....

Comment: Decir *"los primeros"* implica un criterio de orden ¿cuál es?

Comment: Pues por campo "nombre" puede ser

Answer (score 1):

Puedes establecer un contador @counter. Lo inicializas en 0 y guardas en este la cantidad total de registros en la tabla que vas a consultar. Luego divides el porcentaje que deseas consultar y lo divides entre 100 para luego multiplicarlo por el dato en el contador.

```
SELECT* 
FROM (
    SELECT tabla.*, @counter := @counter +1 AS counter 
    FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar, tabla 
    ORDER BY value DESC 
) AS X 
where counter <= (35/100 * @counter); 
ORDER BY value DESC
```

También puede servir que asignes a una variable la cantidad total de registros entre el porcentaje que deseas. Luego ejecutas un Prepared Statement donde en el '?' recibira el valor que posea @amount para luego ejecutarlo:

```
SET @amount =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla) /35; 
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT ?'; 
EXECUTE STMT USING @amount;
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias, una pregunta para que sirve el @. ? Eso nunca lo había visto y/o usado

Comment: el segundo query sugerido me arroja este error:  Unknown prepared statement handler (STMT) given to EXECUTE

Comment: Ejecutaste las 3 lineas a la vez? Debes ejecutarlas como un solo bloque SQL. Acabo de usarlo tal cual sin ningún problema. el '@amount' es una variable, puedes colocarle el nombre que quieras como '@porcentaje' o '@valor' y lo puedes invocar en cualquier parte de tu consulta.

Comment: Por que entre 35??? Lo que necesito son los primeros 35% (por ciento)

Comment: El limit ? (eso existe?) Si existe que significa el (?)

Comment: Te explico. El PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT ?' establece la consulta a ejecutar, el '?' le indica que ahí va a recibir un valor, pero que la consulta no sabe cual es, el solo sabe que va a esperar algo. Luego ejecutas EXECUTE STMT USING '@amount' donde STMT es tu consulta 'SELECT * FROM tabla LIMIT ?' y usaras como valor para sustituir la incógnita '?' lo que almacenaste en '@amount'. Ejemplo: Tu tabla tiene 1000 registros, divide eso entre 35 (que es el porcentaje que deseas) y da 28.5. El va a redondear y te retorna los primeros 28 o 29 registros de la tabla.

Comment: (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prospectos)/35 este query da error

Comment: pero entre 35 no me da el 35% de los registros no?

Comment: colocaste el 'SET @amount =' antes de eso? Arriba en la respuesta esta la estructura de la consulta.

Comment: Mas bien debe ser: select (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prospectos)/35, ese si me jala

Answer (score 0):

Una solución parecida a la de @ernesto-rincon pero utilizando windows functions (MySql >= 8.0):

En la subquery se enumeran la filas, y luego se filtran aquellas cuyo `orden <= (count(*) * 0.35)`.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS orden
       FROM tabla) AS sq
WHERE orden <= (SELECT count(*) * 0.35 FROM tabla);
```

Al enumerar puedes ordenar por nombre (u otra columna):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY nombre ASC) AS orden
       FROM tabla) AS sq
WHERE orden <= (SELECT count(*) * 0.35 FROM tabla);
```

Comment: esos querys me dan error los dos

Comment: ¿Que versión de MySql? son para la 8.0 o superior como aclaré en la respuesta.